# Showing dialog boxes with four buttons

Tags: android, android-layout, android-widget

hy ! i am using dialog im my option . i want four button in that dialog box . i have added three buttons one is
**myDialog.setPositiveButton("Delete", new DialogInterface.OnClickListener()** 
2nd is
**myDialog.setNegativeButton("Cancel", new DialogInterface.OnClickListener()** 
and the 3rd one is  **myDialog.setNeutralButton("Add", new DialogInterface.OnClickListener()** but im unable to add 4th one as i tried one more setPositiveButton but its showing only one .how i can add 4th one plz give me hint.

thank you.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

If you just want to use a notmal dialog something like this should work

```
Dialog settingsDialog = new Dialog(this); 
settingsDialog.getWindow().requestFeature(Window.FEATURE_NO_TITLE); 
settingsDialog.setContentView(getLayoutInflater().inflate(R.layout.button_layout 
        , null)); 
settingsDialog.show();
```

button_layout.xml

```
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android" 
    android:layout_width="wrap_content" android:layout_height="wrap_content" 
    android:orientation="vertical"> 
    <Button android:layout_width="wrap_content" android:layout_height="wrap_content" 
        android:text="OK" android:onClick="dismissListener"/>
    <Button android:layout_width="wrap_content" android:layout_height="wrap_content" 
        android:text="OK" android:onClick="dismissListener"/>
    <Button android:layout_width="wrap_content" android:layout_height="wrap_content" 
        android:text="OK" android:onClick="dismissListener"/> 
    <Button android:layout_width="wrap_content" android:layout_height="wrap_content" 
        android:text="OK" android:onClick="dismissListener"/> 
</LinearLayout>
```

You can create the layout according to your requirement.

Comment: @blessenm how can I add on click listener to the buttons?

Comment: @sanghati-mukherjee I think creating a 'dismissListener' method in the activity should work. Or getLayoutInflater().inflate() method returns a view. Typecast it to a ViewGroup and then use the findViewById or any child selection method to access the button. Once you get the button object you can use the setOnClickListener.

Answer (score 1):

You can't. In that case you must create a [custom view](http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/ui/dialogs.html#CustomDialog) for your `Dialog` and put four buttons at the bottom of that view (at the top, you put a `TextView` with the message).